# Hybrid handler for dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rcpp

I'm writing an hybrid handler for dplyr, and I'm wondering two things about the code in [dplyr.cpp](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/dplyr.cpp):

- The option na.rm is used as a template and not passed as a parameter to the classes Sd, Var, Sum etc. What's the reason?
- What does the line `TAG(arg3) == R_NaRmSymbol` ([line 54](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/dplyr.cpp#L54)) mean?

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not the author of the code, here's my best guesses at answers to your questions:

> The option na.rm is used as a template and not passed as a parameter to the classes Sd, Var, Sum etc. What's the reason?

Likely for run-time efficiency -- `dplyr` tries to move computation from run-time to compile-time when possible. This is often accomplished through template usage.

> What does the line TAG(arg3) == R_NaRmSymbol (line 54) mean?

Nodes in an R pairlist have a `TAG` attribute, which usually refers to the name of the formal. Hence, `dplyr` uses that to find the formal with the name `na.rm`. R caches many of the often-used symbols in [src/main/names.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2c0ada947f4842e6df40a5dd2d77889b9c5d7ba2/src/main/names.c#L1048-L1114) -- you should see `NaRmSymbol` in there.

So, effectively, the code finds the actual argument value associated with the formal `na.rm`, and does stuff based on its truthiness.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I get your first answer though. My hypothesis is it allows to fork the program according the option na.rm only once, instead of forking it for each group defined by the operator group_by. Would that make sense?